# Call server every 5 seconds - returns stack overflow error

Tags: angularjs

I want to call a method on an interval of time. I am receiving stack overflow error. What am I doing wrong:

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <span>{{calledServer}}</span>
</div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope, repo, poollingFactory) {
    $scope.calledServer;
    $scope.calledServer = poollingFactory.callFnOnInterval(function() {return repo.callServer(5);});
});

app.factory("repo", function() {

    function callServer(id){
        return "call server with id " + id;   
    }

    return {
        callServer: callServer
    };
});

app.factory("poollingFactory", function($timeout) {

    var timeIntervalInSec = 5;

    function callFnOnInterval(fn, timeInterval) {

        $timeout(callFnOnInterval, 1000 * timeIntervalInSec);
        callFnOnInterval(fn, timeIntervalInSec);
    };

    return {
        callFnOnInterval: callFnOnInterval
    };
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fq4vg/423/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a recursive call that isn't checking for any precondition.

An annotated version of your function:

```
function callFnOnInterval(fn, timeInterval) {

  //Schedule a call to 'callFnOnInterval' to happen in one second
  // and return immediately
  $timeout(callFnOnInterval, 1000 * timeIntervalInSec);

  //Immediately make a call to 'callFnOnInterval' which will repeat
  // this process ad-infinitum
  callFnOnInterval(fn, timeIntervalInSec);

};
```

Because you keep pushing calls onto the stack recursively and never returning, it eventually runs out of space.

Since the `$timeout` service returns a promise, you can use that to schedule more work once it is complete.

Here is what your service should probably look like:

```
app.factory("poollingFactory", function ($timeout) {

   var timeIntervalInSec = 5;

   function callFnOnInterval(fn, timeInterval) {

       var promise = $timeout(fn, 1000 * timeIntervalInSec);

       return promise.then(function(){
           callFnOnInterval(fn, timeInterval);
       });
   };

   return {
       callFnOnInterval: callFnOnInterval
   };
});
```

And here is an example jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/cXX2S/

**A few notes about your code above.**

You are trying to set a scope property value to the return of your `callFnOnInterval` but that isn't going to work. First, it doesn't return anything. Second, because it is an asynchronous call, at best it could return a `promise`.

Answer (score 4):

Your timeout method is calling itself until he runs out of space.

If you want to do something every x seconds use the $interval method.

```
app.factory("poollingFactory", function($interval) {

var timeIntervalInSec = 5;

function callFnOnInterval(fn, timeInterval) {
    return $interval(fn, 1000 * timeIntervalInSec);        
};

return {
    callFnOnInterval: callFnOnInterval
};
});
```

by the way, to get the result of the method back into your scope property you have to change the call to:

```
 poollingFactory.callFnOnInterval(function() {return $scope.calledServer = repo.callServer(5);});
```